# FFmpeg gap in concatenated audio after splitting audio

Tags: ffmpeg

Not sure if it's a gap or just misaligned audio samples, but when i split an audio file in two, like this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 00:00:15.00 -i song.mp3 seg1.mp3
```

and

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:15.00 -t 15 -i song.mp3 seg2.mp3
```

and then combine them again with concat filter:

```
ffmpeg -i 'concat:seg1.mp3|seg2.mp3' out.mp3
```

There is a distinct "pop" between the segments. How can i make this seamless?

I see this on seg2.mp3:

```
Duration: 00:00:15.05, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 128 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
```

Why is "start" not 0? That could be the gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to eliminate the gap I recommend using the [atrim](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atrim) and [concat](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex \
"[0:a]atrim=end=15[a0]; \
 [0:a]atrim=start=15:end=30[a1]; \
 [a0][a1]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1" \
output.mp3
```

Note that [MP3 files may have silence/delay at the beginning and end](http://lame.sourceforge.net/tech-FAQ.txt), so using individually encoded segments is not ideal.